# LDAP Authentication for Nifi on HDP Sandbox

Tags: ldap, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have enabled Demo LDAP(Available with Knox Service) on HDP Sandbox and trying to use it to configure Nifi Authentication. I configured couple of xml files as below but dont see any exception in nifi-app.logs. Its not prompting me for username/password while accessing.

```
vim /opt/nifi/current/conf/login-identity-providers.xml
<loginIdentityProviders>
<provider>
<identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
<class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
<property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>
<property name="Manager DN">uid=guest,ou=people,dc=hadoop,dc=apache,dc=org</property>
<property name="Manager Password">guest-password</property>
<property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
<property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
<property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>
<property name="Url">ldap://localhost:33389</property>
<property name="User Search Base">ou=people,dc=hadoop,dc=apache,dc=org</property>
<property name="User Search Filter">uid={0}</property>
<property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
</provider>
</loginIdentityProviders>
```

Authorizer.xml

```
vim /opt/nifi/current/conf/authorizers.xml

<authorizer>
        <identifier>file-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Authorizations File">/opt/nifi/current/conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Users File">/opt/nifi/current/conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">uid=guest,ou=people,dc=hadoop,dc=apache,dc=org</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <!-- Provide the identity (typically a DN) of each node when clustered, see above description of Node Identity.
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 2"></property>
        -->
    </authorizer>
```

nifi.properties

```
# Core Properties #
nifi.version=1.0.0
nifi.flow.configuration.file=/opt/nifi/data/conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=/opt/nifi/data/conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=/opt/nifi/current/conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=/opt/nifi/current/conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=/opt/nifi/data/conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=/opt/nifi/data/flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.partitions=256
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=2 mins
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000
nifi.swap.in.period=5 sec
nifi.swap.in.threads=1
nifi.swap.out.period=5 sec
nifi.swap.out.threads=4

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=10 MB
nifi.content.claim.max.flow.files=100
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=/opt/nifi/data/content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=12 hours
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=false
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=/nifi-content-viewer/

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=com.thinkbiganalytics.nifi.provenance.repo.KyloPersistentProvenanceEventRepository

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=/opt/nifi/data/provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=24 hours
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=1 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=30 secs
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=1
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.provenance.repository.journal.count=16
# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are: 
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uuid, mime.type
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is retrieved.
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536

# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component Status Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec

# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=8079
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.keystore=
nifi.security.keystoreType=
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.security.keyPasswd=
nifi.security.truststore=
nifi.security.truststoreType=
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=
nifi.security.needClientAuth=
nifi.security.user.authorizer=file-provider
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principle #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principle #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=
```

Any thought on issue ? Anything in missing in configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache NiFi only performs user authentication and authorization when it is configured to run over HTTPS (the design decision was made because HTTP requests can be intercepted, spoofed, compromised, etc.). See [User Authentication](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#user_authentication) and [Security Configuration](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security-configuration) to set that up (and here is a great [step-by-step tutorial](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy) on configuring this from Bryan Bende).